# How does regularized logistic regression regularize perceptron hypothesis set in binary classifcation task?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, logistic, perceptron

I'm a newbie to Machine Learning and I'm not very good at math. I have read [Learning From Data - A Short Course](http://www.amlbook.com/index.html) and met this Exercise 4.6 on page 133:

> We have seen both the hard-order constraint and the soft-order
>   constraint. Which do you expect to be more useful for binary
>   classification using the perceptron model? *[Hint: $ sign(w^{T}x) =
> \> sign(\alpha w^{T}x) $ for any $ \alpha > 0 $.]*

From the hint of the question, I have guessed the answer: Soft-order constraint does not actually "regularize" the perceptron model at all (I'm not sure if I used the right word here, what I mean is that soft-order constraint does not "reduce" the "complexity" of the hypothesis set of the perceptron model), and so the hard-order constraint is more useful for binary classification using the perceptron model.

However, if the above answer is correct, then I do not understand how regularized logistic regression regularize perceptron hypothesis set in the above binary classification task?